# separar datos de un campo mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, print

Tengo esta consulta en `mysql` que genera un **print** de pantalla con un número

```
<?php $contratos_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_CONTRATOS . "");
$contratos = tep_db_fetch_array($contratos_query);?>
```

La pantalla muestra con este comando el numero completo

```
<?php echo $contratos['numero_contrato'] ; ?>
```

> Ejemplo: 8787E01 = numero_contrato

Tengo que separar dos campos de la misma celda donde **8787** es el número de contrato y **E01** es la entrega

necesito un **print** de pantalla donde solo muestre **los primeros 4 digitos**

print: 8787

y otro donde solo muestre los **3 ultimos digitos**.

```
print: E01
```

> Nota: todos los numero_contrato de la tabla siempre tienen la misma longitud el contrato son 4 primeros números y están a la izquierda
>   y las entregas siempre son 3 últimos números y están a la derecha.

de que manera logro un **print** que el `<?php echo $contratos['numero_contrato'] ; ?>` solo muestre **los primeros 4 dígitos** y luego otro `print <?php echo $contratos['numero_contrato'] ; ?>` que solo muestre **los 3 últimos**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consideremos la siguiente función para recortar un string.

> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Teniendo esta función en cuenta, aplicaremos lo siguiente:

```
<?php $numContrato = $contratos['numero_contrato']; ?>
```

Solo si no puedes abrir dos veces el array de mysql, lo entregaremos en una variable, y con ella manipularemos lo siguiente

**Contrato**

```
<?php echo substr($numContrato,0,4) ; ?> //primeras 4 digitos
```

**Entrega**

```
<?php echo substr($numContrato,-3) ; ?> //primeras 3 digitos
```

Lo que hace es simplemente cortar el string.
En el primer caso, esta desde la posición 0, contar 4 caracteres hacia derecha.
En el segundo caso, ve desde la ultima letra y cuenta 3 hacia la izquierda.

Posteriormente mostramos lo cortado.

Documentación extraída directamente de php.net

http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php

Checka la documentación, hay varias cosas interesantes.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar la instrucción `substr`

> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

donde:
**$string** Es la cadena donde buscar
**$start**: Posición desde donde quieres empezar, el primer caracter es el 0
**$length:** Es el número de caracteres que quieres obtener.

Con esto, tu consulta quedaría

**contrato**

```
<?php echo string substr ($contratos['numero_contrato'], 0, 4) ; ?>
```

**Entrega**

```
<?php echo string substr ($contratos['numero_contrato'], 4, 3) ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Habrá sin duda varias formas de hacer esto, pero quizá lo más sencillo será usar [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php), **indicándole que me divida la cadena a partir del carácter 4**. Opcionalmente, también validaría la longitud de la cadena con [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php). Por si lo necesitas en más partes del código, puedes crear una función para ello.

La función sería sencillamente esto:

```
function dividirCadena($strDatos){
    $arrResultado=(strlen($strDatos)==7) ? str_split($strDatos, 4) : null;
    return $arrResultado;
}
```

Devolvería la cadena dividida en dos, o `null`si no tuviera `7`caracteres.

Lo de la validación es algo opcional, que puedes hacer o no (yo valido siempre los datos, uno nunca sabe). No obstante, si quieres prescindir de ello, la cadena se puede dividir con tan solo esto:

```
$arrResultado=str_split($strDatos, 4);
echo $arrResultado[0];
echo $arrResultado[1];
```

En tu caso, `$arrResultado` será un array con dos valores:

- en la posición 0: 8787
- en la posición 1: E01

---

#### Prueba de concepto

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/CKI37188)**</kbd>

```
<?php
/*https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131971/29967*/

/*Datos de prueba con cadena válida*/
$strDatos="8787E01";
$strFinal=dividirCadena($strDatos);

if ($strFinal){
    echo $strFinal[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo $strFinal[1].PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Cadena inválida".PHP_EOL;
}


/*Datos de prueba con cadena inválida*/
$strDatos="8787E019";
$strFinal=dividirCadena($strDatos);

if ($strFinal){
    echo $strFinal[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo $strFinal[1].PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Cadena inválida".PHP_EOL;
}

/*Función*/
function dividirCadena($strDatos){
    $arrResultado=(strlen($strDatos)==7) ? str_split($strDatos, 4) : null;
    return $arrResultado;
}
?>
```

---

**Resultado:**

Cuando la cadena sea válida:

```
8787
E01
```

Cuando no sea válida:

```
Cadena inválida
```